# Making an automated update for mySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently trying to create an automated script in order to update my mysql database once in a while. What i do is call an external API to fetch the current data, extract only the information i need and make query into my database to update existing data and insert new ones.

```
$context = stream_context_create($headers);

    $string = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    $json = json_decode($string);

    $data = $json->data;

    foreach ($data as $dat){

        echo $dat->name . "\t\n";
        echo $dat->title . "\t\n";
        echo $dat->image->full . "\t\n";
    }




    if(!$connection){
        die("Database server connection failed.");  
    }
    else{
        $dbconnect = mysqli_select_db($conn, "test");

        if(!$dbconnect){
            die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
        }
        else{
            foreach ($data as $dat){

                $query = "UPDATE CAR SET C_NAME = '" . $dat->name . "', C_TITLE= '" . $dat->title . "', C_IMAGE= '" . $dat->image->full . "';";

                $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                if (! $resultset){

                    $query = "INSERT INTO CAR (c_name, c_title, c_image) VALUES( '" . $dat->name . "', '" . $dat->title . "', '" . $dat->image->full . "';";

                    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    if (! $resultset){
                        die ('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                        echo "error";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "success INSERT";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "success UPDATE";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The first part where i call the API and extract the data i need works just fine because i print them for debugging and they all show up as intented. for the next part i get printed only four times 'success UPDATE' and then one 'Could not enter data'

The main purpose is to first update existing data into the database, and if in case there are more entries for example a new car, to use the insert into query and put that along with the rest.

Comment: @Strawberry So what should i do? i am not very familiar databases and web development. I thought this was just normal to do.

Comment: No. You would build a single "INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" using all the values and then execute it once.

Comment: @Strawberry Could you give me an example please? as i told you im not familiar with databases, i kind of understand what you mean but i don't know how to construct that query.

Comment: @Strawberry I also have an c_id which is the first field in my database and have c_id + c_name as primary key, if that helps.

Comment: That seems like a really odd choice for a PRIMARY KEY. Surely c_id is PRIMARY, and c_name (or, more likely, [c_name,c_model]) is UNIQUE

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, so i changed my database and made c_id primary key and c_name, c_image UNIQUE. do you have some good resource or example code about "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" with more than one value. plus i want to make sure that "on duplicate key does not mean the c_id, cuz the c_name (or the whole row) must not be duplicate too.

Comment: Other questions in SO have already tackled this. The VALUES() function is key